# for each selected listitem

Tags: delphi, listview, listitem

I try to do an action for each selected listitem but it won't work.
This is what i tried:

```
var
TLsttem:TListItem;
begin
for TLsttem in form1.listview1.Selected do
begin
...
end;
end;
```

Now i get this error:

> [dcc32 Error] MSGBox.pas(50): E2431 for-in statement cannot operate on
>   collection type 'TListItem' because 'TListItem' does not contain a
>   member for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible

How can i fix this?

EDIT:
I now tried this script:

```
TLsttem := form1.ListView1.Selected;
    while TLsttem <> nil do
    begin
    showmessage('Test');
    TLsttem := form1.ListView1.GetNextItem(TLsttem, sdAll, [isSelected]);
  end;
```

But i only get 1 message, how can i fix this?

Comment: You can't iterate over a single item (the `Selected` property returns the current selected TListItem) instead you must use `Items` property which returns a collection.

Comment: Why are you using `form1` global variable? I bet that the code runs inside a method of `TForm1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example is from documentation, [`GetNextItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/GetNextItem_(Delphi)):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Selected;
  while Item <> nil do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Item.Caption);
    Item := ListView1.GetNextItem(Item, sdAll, [isSelected]);
  end;
end;
```

[`TListView.Selected`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.Selected) gets the first selected item, while [`GetNextItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.GetNextItem) unwinds more selected items.

[image]

---

As noted by David, it is possible to wrap this logic into an enumerator, so that a `for .. in` loop could be used.
The easiest thing is to put this enumeration into a class helper, much like the answer from [`@StefanGlienke`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182198/576719).

```
type
  TSelectedListItemsEnumerator = record
  private
    FListView: TListView;
    FItem: TListItem;
  public
    constructor Create(aListView: TListView);
    function GetEnumerator: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator;
    function MoveNext: Boolean;
    property Current: TListItem read FItem;
  end;

  TListViewHelper = class helper for TListView
  private
    function GetSelectedItems: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator;
  public
    property SelectedItems: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator
      read GetSelectedItems;
  end;

{ TSelectedListItemsEnumerator }

constructor TSelectedListItemsEnumerator.Create(aListView: TListView);
begin
  FListView := AListView;
end;

function TSelectedListItemsEnumerator.GetEnumerator: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator;
begin
  FItem := nil;
  Result := Self;
end;

function TSelectedListItemsEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  FItem := FListView.GetNextItem(FItem,sdAll,[isSelected]);
  Result := (FItem <> nil);
end;

{ TListViewHelper }

function TListViewHelper.GetSelectedItems: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator;
begin
  Result := TSelectedListItemsEnumerator.Create(Self);
end;
```

---

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  for Item in ListView1.SelectedItems do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Item.Caption);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 also. New to me too. Is this implemented in the VCL, or is it a service provided by the underlying control. Could be wrapped up nicely in an enumerator.

Comment: Can you please reply on my edit?
I used your source but only nog the part that i add an item to the listview

Comment: @user2735398, just tried in XE4, works fine. `TListView.MultiSelect = True` and `ViewStyle = vsList`. Try to output the `Item.Caption`to a memo or similar.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it is provided by the underlying control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, made an enumerator. I'm sure it could be more compact, but this works.

Comment: I am not sure what to say about copying the code from my answer and only making slight modifications to it even with mentioning and after you got the accepted answer.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, sorry if I was to rough. Made the enumeration more compact now. The iteration here steps internally only through the selected items, which was the point of adding this enumeration example.

Comment: @LURD No problem. I actually did not think of combining the enumerable and enumerator into one type (althouh I have done that before aswell), so +1 now :) You can make it shorter btw if you are just using FItem, initialize it with nil on GetEnumerator and then just `FItem := FListView.GetNextItem(FItem, sdAll, [isSelected]); Result := Assigned(FItem);` in MoveNext. You can even get rid of the extra GetCurrent method that way.

Comment: @StefanGlienke, thank you very much for those hints. Updated the example.

Comment: The first one was what I needed—a simple script to get all selected items into a Memo. Now, I have to loop through the lines.

Answer (score 5):

While for this example it might be overkill here is a way to extend the TListView class with a SelectedItem property that is enumerable with a for-in loop.

In cases where the condition inside the loop might be more complex than just checking a property or by actually providing a filter delegate this can be very powerful.

```
type
  TSelectedListItemsEnumerator = class(TListItemsEnumerator)
  public
    function MoveNext: Boolean;
  end;

  TSelectedListItemsEnumerable = record
  private
    FListItems: TListItems;
  public
    constructor Create(AListItems: TListItems);
    function GetEnumerator: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator;
  end;

  TListViewHelper = class helper for TListView
  private
    function GetSelectedItems: TSelectedListItemsEnumerable;
  public
    property SelectedItems: TSelectedListItemsEnumerable
      read GetSelectedItems;
  end;

{ TSelectedListItemsEnumerator }

function TSelectedListItemsEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  repeat
    Result := inherited;
  until not Result or Current.Selected;
end;

{ TSelectedListItemsEnumerable }

constructor TSelectedListItemsEnumerable.Create(AListItems: TListItems);
begin
  FListItems := AListItems;
end;

function TSelectedListItemsEnumerable.GetEnumerator: TSelectedListItemsEnumerator;
begin
  Result := TSelectedListItemsEnumerator.Create(fListItems);
end;

{ TListViewHelper }

function TListViewHelper.GetSelectedItems: TSelectedListItemsEnumerable;
begin
  Result := TSelectedListItemsEnumerable.Create(Items);
end;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TListItem;
begin
  for item in ListView1.SelectedItems do
  begin
    ShowMessage(item.Caption);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

This works perfectly fine for me in XE5 (VCL):

```
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  for Item in ListView1.Items do
  begin
    if Item.Selected then
    begin
      // Do something with the item
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This will only take the first item in the listview

Comment: @user2735398: No, it doesn't. :-) It loops through each item, testing for whether each item is selected.

Comment: However, @LURD's answer is better.